# Do I need to take build from Xcode 6 for an old app update (already in App Store)?

Tags: ios, app-store

Is it possible to submit an update with Xcode 5.* ? Sorry for being very specific, I have no idea how to present this question. I can't check this right away because that particular account is managed by my client.

I have seen this from apple documentation,

> Starting February 1, 2015, new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store must
>   include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK, included in
>   Xcode 6 or later.

Here they specified clearly that for new app we must take build from Xcode 6.*. But nothing about update of something already in app Store?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read below

64-bit and iOS 8 Requirements for App Updates

December 17, 2014
 beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need to follow the same requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.

https://developer.apple.com/news/

So after 1st june 2015 you need to compulsory use xcode 6 to upload build into app store. Till that time you can upload via xcode 5.

Comment: click on the link and check all the news for apple developers

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to submit anything to the AppStore that is not done with one of the latest versions of `Xcode`. There is a grace periode of a few weeks for previous `Xcode` and `SDK` versions but for `Xcode 5.x` that is long over.
With the `SDK` it's similar, but of course you can support older `SDK` versions as well - you just need to have (one of) the latest installed.

This is true for new apps as well as any updates to existing apps, there is no difference.